# Let $\psi:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, $\psi\neq0$, solution of the differential equation $y'=f(x)y$. Prove solution is unique.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $\psi:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, $\psi\neq0$, solution of the differential equation $$y'=f(x)y.$$
>
> $i$) Find the general form of the solution if $\psi(b)=a,$ with $ b\in I.$
>
> $ii$) Prove that the solution is unique.

So my try with the first section was the one below:

$i$) Let's assume $\psi$ is a solution. We have:

$$\psi'=f(x)\psi\implies \frac{\psi'}{\psi}=f(x) \implies ln|\psi|+C=\int_b^xf(t)dt\implies$$$$\implies \psi=a\cdot e^{\int_b^xf(t)dt}$$

which is the general form of the solution of the differential equation given.

Now I'm completely stuck with $ii)$. While it's obvious it's the only solution possible for that differential equation, I cannot use Lipschitz to prove uniqueness, so I don't know how to formally prove it.

**EDIT**

$ii$) We see that $|f(x)y_1-f(x)y_2|=|f(x)|\cdot |y_1-y_2|\leq |max\{f(x)\}_{x\in I}|\cdot |y_1-y_2|$.

So it's Lipschitz, and hence by Picard there's only one solution, which is $\psi$.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: surely it is lipschitz so you can use picard lindelof

Comment: picard lindelof requires only that the RHS is uniformly lipchitz in y

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Let me post my try so we can see if it's correct. Editing it.

Comment: @Relure I assume that the function $f$ defined on open interval $I$ is continuous. In this case, $f$ needs not be bounded. In fact, $a\cdot \exp(\int_b^x f(t)dt)$ is well-defined even $f$ is unbounded on $I$. For example, $I=(0,\infty)$ and $f(t)=t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that either

(1): For each $x\in I$, $\varphi(x)>0$, or

(2): For each $x\in I,$ $\varphi(x)<0$.

It is because if there exists $x_{1},x_{2}\in I$ such that $\varphi(x_{1})>0$
and $\varphi(x_{2})<0$, then, by intermediate value theorem, there
exists $\xi$ strictly between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ such that $\varphi(\xi)=0$,
which contradicts to the assumption $\varphi\neq0$. (See the proposition in the second part)

Whether (1) holds or (2) holds depends on the sign of $a$.

Without loss of generality, we consider the case that $a>0$. Suppose
that $\varphi_{1}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi_{2}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
are differentiable, never-zero, and satisfy $\varphi_{1}'(x)=f(x)\varphi_{1}(x)$,
$\varphi_{2}'(x)=f(x)\varphi_{2}(x)$. From the above discussion,
$\varphi_{1}>0$ and $\varphi_{2}>0$. Therefore the composite functions
$\ln\varphi_{1}$ and $\ln\varphi_{2}$ are well-defined and are differentiable.
For each $x\in I$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\ln\varphi_{1}\right)'(x) & = & \frac{\varphi_{1}'(x)}{\varphi_{1}(x)}\\
 & = & f(x)\\
 & = & \frac{\varphi_{2}'(x)}{\varphi_{2}(x)}\\
 & = & \left(\ln\varphi_{2}\right)'(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
By mean-value theorem, there exists $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left(\ln\varphi_{1}\right)(x)=C+\left(\ln\varphi_{2}\right)(x)$
for each $x\in I$. Hence, 
$$
\varphi_{1}(x)=e^{C}\varphi_{2}(x).
$$
Put $x=b$, then we obtain $a=e^{C}a$ and hence $e^{C}=1$. Therefore,
$\varphi_{1}(x)=\varphi_{2}(x)$.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

To fill a gap, we need the following proposition.

Proposition: Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Let
$f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $\varphi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
a differentiable function such that $\varphi'(x)=f(x)\varphi(x)$.
If there exists $a\in I$ such that $\varphi(a)=0$, then $\varphi(x)=0$
for all $x\in I$.

Proof: Let $A=\{x\in(a,\infty)\cap I\mid\varphi(x)\neq0\}$. We go
to prove that $A=\emptyset$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose the
contrary that $A\neq\emptyset$. Clearly $A$ is bounded below by
$a$, so $a'=\inf A$ exists. If $\varphi(a')\neq0$, then there exists
$\delta>0$ such that $\varphi(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in(a'-\delta,a'+\delta)$.
In particular, $a'-\frac{1}{2}\delta\in A$, contradicting to the
fact that $a'=\inf A$. Therefore $\varphi(a')=0$.

Choose $\delta>0$ such that $[a',a'+\delta]\subseteq I$. Choose
$M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ and $|\varphi(x)|\leq M$ for all
$x\in[a',a'+\delta]$. Let $\delta'=\min(\delta,\frac{1}{2M})>0$.
Let $x_{0}\in(a',a'+\delta')$ be arbitrary. By mean-value theorem,
there exists $x_{1}\in(a',x_{0})$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\varphi(x_{0})\right| & = & \left|\varphi(x_{0})-\varphi(a')\right|\\
 & = & \left|\varphi'(x_{1})(x_{0}-a')\right|\\
 & = & \left|f(x_{1})\varphi(x_{1})(x_{0}-a')\right|\\
 & \leq & M\cdot\frac{1}{2M}\cdot\left|\varphi(x_{1})\right|\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}\left|\varphi(x_{1})\right|.
\end{eqnarray*}
By mean-value theorem again, there exists $x_{2}\in(a',x_{1})$ such
that $\varphi(x_{1})-\varphi(a')=\varphi'(x_{2})(x_{1}-a')$. Hence
$\left|\varphi(x_{1})\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}|\varphi(x_{2})|$. By
recursion theorem, we can choose a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{0}>x_{1}>\ldots>a'$
and $|\varphi(x_{n})|\leq\frac{1}{2}|\varphi(x_{n+1})|$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Hence, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
|\varphi(x_{0})| & \leq & \frac{1}{2^{n}}|\varphi(x_{n})|\\
 & \leq & \frac{M}{2^{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\varphi(x_{0})=0$. That is, $\varphi(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a',a'+\delta')$.
On the other hand, $a'+\delta'$ is not a lower bound of $A$, so
there exists $\xi\in A$ such that $a'\leq\xi<a'+\delta'$.
That is, $\xi\in[a',a'+\delta')$ and $\varphi(\xi)\neq0$, which
is a contradiction.

Similarly, we can prove that $\{x\in(-\infty,a)\cap I\mid\varphi(x)\neq0\}=\emptyset$.
Hence, $\varphi(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: Sorry. I mixed up the symbols $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: I miss a point: If your $\psi\neq 0$ means the negation of "for each $x\in I$, $\psi(x)=0$", then I still need to show the fact: There exists $x_0$ such that $\psi(x_0)=0\Rightarrow$ for each $x\in I$, $\psi(x)=0$.